# Format DateTime dependency Property as text (String)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

**EDIT: Gettign Xaml parse errors when trying to implement a convertor**

Error: *Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.*

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148" 
                                                  Margin="10,0,5,0" 
                                                  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}"
                                                  Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
                                                  Title="{Binding Title}"
                                                  Oorzaak="{Binding Oorzaak}"

                                                  DuurStilstand="{Binding DuurStilstand, 
                                                        Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConvertor},  
                                                        ConverterParameter=\{0:t\}}"

                                                  BeginStilstand="{Binding BeginStilstand}"
                                                  />
                </DataTemplate>
```

IValueConvertor:

```
    public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
        {
            return string.Format(culture, formatString, value);

        }
        // If the format string is null or empty, simply call ToString()
        // on the value.
        return value.ToString();
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

Currently i have a String Dependency property that uses binding and displays everything correct. Although this property should be DateTime instead. I am using Strings all over my application for calculations and this should be done one DateTime values instead.

I get nothing but binding errors when i try to change this to DateTime. Before the Property was of type String.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DuurStilstandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DuurStilstand", typeof(DateTime), typeof(RegistrationButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

public DateTime DuurStilstand
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DuurStilstandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DuurStilstandProperty, value); }
    }
```

The XAML Binding:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbDuurStilstand" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="{Binding DuurStilstand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Margin="7.5,5,0,0" Height="24.8266666666667"/>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148" 
                                                  Margin="10,0,5,0" 
                                                  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}"
                                                  Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
                                                  Title="{Binding Title}"
                                                  Oorzaak="{Binding Oorzaak}"
                                                  DuurStilstand="{Binding DuurStilstand}"
                                                  BeginStilstand="{Binding BeginStilstand}"
                                                  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**Error shows up here (XamlParseException):**

```
<myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="btnTestRegistration" Content="Test Registratie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16.8,0,0,118.14" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="119.2" Height="30.2" FontSize="18.667" Click="btnTestRegistration_Click" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}" />
```

Why am i unable to change this to DateTime.

The textblock requires a String instead of a DateTime it is currently getting now. How exactly do i make sure it converts the DateTime to a String when the content is placed in the .text property of the textblock?

Best regards, PeterP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the best soluiton, in my opinion, is make use of [Binding Converters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx), to and from the binded data.

```
public class DateTimeConverter: IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo 
        {

           DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
           //convert back to string from dt 

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
          string dateTimeString = value as string; 

           //Convert to DateTime from dateTimeString 
        }
    }
```

define ins say App.xaml

```
<DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter" />
```

and bind to your property

```
<myClasses:RegistrationButton x:Name="RegistrationButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="148" 
                                                  Margin="10,0,5,0" 
                                                  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleRegistration}"
                                                  Click="RegistrationButton_Click"
                                                  Title="{Binding Title}"
                                                  Oorzaak="{Binding Oorzaak}"
                                                  DuurStilstand="{Binding DuurStilstand}"
                                                  BeginStilstand="{Binding BeginStilstand}"
                                                  Converter = {StaticResource DateTimeConverter }


                        />
```

Comment: Hello Tigran. Is it not the other way around Convert to Formatstring in Convert or am  i getting this wrong? Bit confused on what to return here (hh:mm:ss).

Comment: @PeterP: you're right. Just corrected, typo error.. too fast.

Comment: I tried implementing but i am getting a parse error and i do not know for what reason. Will post some short code on top of the post. What exactly am i doing wrong? Tried implementing a convertor earlier today but i failed due to xmal parse errors as well. Best regards.

Comment: @PeterP: it seems to me that on Convert you get a string, but return a string too! You have to return DateTime, as binded property is DateTime (at least based on your post)

Comment: Hmm my current property is a DateTime i wish to convert it to a String in my binding property. I am confused :/ My application keeps on crashing now. Can you maybe show me what to exactly return cause i do not understand it atm? Cheers.  /Peter

Comment: I also believe its not finding my Convertor class in the xaml binding. "{"Cannot find resource named 'DateTimeConvertor'. Resource names are case sensitive."}" How do i refer to this class in the XAML?  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterP: You will keep getting parse errors until you fix that default value for your property, as both me and Coding Gorilla have pointed out.

Comment: Hi Matt, i already fixed that and that solved half of the problem ;)

Comment: @PeterP: To use a converter you need to create an instance of it. Usually you add it to the resources of the window (or any control if you want), give it a key and refer to it using StaticResource.

Comment: Ok cheers for the help guys i finally got this working...! Only the formatting seems to be wrong since its displays the full datetime instead of hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you're talking about conversion (from DateTime to string) you can simply add an **IValueConverter** to your binding. The following MSDN article has an example that shows how to convert from DateTime to string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DuurStilstandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DuurStilstand", typeof(DateTime), typeof(RegistrationButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

You can use a DateTime, but WPF will need to coerce the values that are provided to a DateTime, and you're `UIPropertyMetadata([defaultvalue])` is an empty string which cannot be cooerced to a DateTime.  You should use something like `UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue).

Also, I would suggest that you apply `IValueConverter`s to your bindings so that you're not relying on WPF to cooerce the strings, which very well maybe un-coercable, and instead have a some logic in the converter to handle things appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of your property you are setting the default value to an empty string. Obviously this is invalid for a DateTime! You need to provide a default value that is actually compatible with the type of the property.

Try this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DuurStilstandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DuurStilstand", typeof(DateTime), typeof(RegistrationButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue));
```

You can substitute MinValue for whatever makes sense as a default for you (maybe DateTime.Now).

For actually formatting the date when you bind it you can either use StringFormat or a converter, as others have suggested.

**Edit**

Per you problem with using the convertor. You need to create an instance of the converter and then you can refer to it. For example, you can do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use it like this:

```
DuurStilstand="{Binding DuurStilstand, 
      Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},  
      ConverterParameter=\{0:t\}}"
```